# How do I use 'where' in Dart? '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Class) => bool' of 'test'

Tags: dart

I am using search delegate and I'm trying to filter out search results using `where`.

Currently, the following works:

```
            suggestionList = snapshot.data
                .where((c) => c.number == query || c.words.contains(query))
                .toList(); // can abstract this out in the future
```

I'm trying to abstract out the boolean test to my Chorus class itself and this does not work:

```
            suggestionList = snapshot.data
                .where((c) => c.isMatching(query))
                .toList();
```

Abstraction is here.

```
class Chorus {
  bool isMatching(String query) {
    bool isMatching = false;
    var queryFormatted =
        query.toLowerCase().replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'), '');
    var wordsFormatted =
        words.toLowerCase().replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'), '');
    if (query == this.number) {
      isMatching = true;
    }
    if (wordsFormatted.contains(queryFormatted)) {
      isMatching = true;
    }
    return isMatching;
  }
}
```

This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem with casting the returned value as a bool.

```
suggestionList = snapshot.data
                .where((c) => c.isMatching(query) as bool)
               .toList();
```

Will appreciate if anyone can explain why there's a need to cast it.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but probably you used `AsyncSnapshot` without explicitly specifying the data type (e.g. `AsyncSnapshot<List<Chorus>>`) which ended up being `AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>`.  Later when you try to use `.where()`, because `snapshot.data` is `dynamic`, nothing can be inferred about the callback's argument type and return type, so it also will be assumed to be `dynamic Function(dynamic)`.